# How to execute script written in main html file from another html page loaded using jquery load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two files **index.html** and **subpage.html**. Using jquery `load()` i am loading **subpage.html** into a div `#result` in **index.html**.

I have written js **in index.html** for both `index.html` & `subpage.html`.

Pages goes like this:

**index.html:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("document").ready(function(e) {
      $("#result").load('subpage.html');
   });

</script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

**subpage.html:**

```
<p>Sub page</p>
<input type="button" id="clickMe" value="Click" />
```

But here, **click function written in index** for button `#clickMe` is not triggering while clicking the button.

Is there any possible way to make this happen?

Comment: you should use `.on()` for triggering, and provide a fiddle please

Comment: Because you are loading the subpage.html after the document.ready in the index.html, your event handler is not attaching to #clickMe because #clickMe doesn't exist. I would guess by your use of the # referring to an id you are using jQuery. So you can put a dummy class on #clickMe and attach the event handler to that class rather than the DOM element. Then your handler should work properly with this load order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the `.on` delegation, you have to attach the event to a higher level element and specify the object or class as the delegate.

```
$('body').on('click',"#clickMe", function(){
alert('clicked dynamic dom element');

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You said it boss. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function to set your Event handler, and do not forget to use [`.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) for setting triggers. and afer `$("#result").load('subpage.html');`, call that function.

```
function setEventHandler(){
    $('#clickMe').off('click').on('click',function(){
        // codes here
        alert('Clicked');
    });
}
```

and your codes will be :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("document").ready(function(e) {
      $("#result").load('subpage.html');
      setEventHandler();
   });

</script>

<div id="result"></div>
```